# GNU Make shell function breaks when piped to cut

Tags: gnu-make

Hello I have a MVE where I am trying to catenate two variables and then pipe to cut.

```
all:
    @echo $(APP_NAME)
    @echo $(CURRENT_BRANCH)
    @echo $(call EB_SAFE_NAME,$(CURRENT_BRANCH))
    @echo $(shell echo "$(APP_NAME)-$(call EB_SAFE_NAME,$(CURRENT_BRANCH))" | cut -c 23)
```

Output:

```
   $ cicdtest
   $ issue#13-support-multi-branch
   $ issue-13-support-multi-branch
   $ o
```

If I remove the `| cut -c 23` then the output is fine, but I do need to limit to 23 char. What am I doing wrong on the 4th echo statement above?

Comment: Looks fine to me. `cut` selects the contents of column 23, which is `o` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different behavior in a test script then in make, but the issue is with explicit use of cut, not with make. The following works as expected:

`@echo $(shell echo $(APP_NAME)-$(call EB_SAFE_NAME,$(CURRENT_BRANCH)) | cut -c 1-23)`

Cut has some handling for the incomplete range, but in make (even though I am using bash) the complete range is needed:

> Bytes, characters, and fields are are numbered starting at 1 and separated by commas.
>   Incomplete ranges can be given: -M means 1-M  ;  N- means N through end of line or last field.
>
> Options
>
> -b BYTE-LIST
>   --bytes=BYTE-LIST
>        Print only the bytes in positions listed in BYTE-LIST.  Tabs and
>        backspaces are treated like any other character; they take up 1
>        byte.
>
> -c CHARACTER-LIST
>   --characters=CHARACTER-LIST
>        Print only characters in positions listed in CHARACTER-LIST.  The
>        same as `-b' for now, but internationalization will change that.
>        Tabs and backspaces are treated like any other character; they
>        take up 1 character.